# find id thru class in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Been working on this for hours every solution I found on the web returns "undefined".
I have a form submitted thru jquery validation plugin using ajax.
response returns  .... 
the id changes depending on the data its like this

```
<div class="item" id="item-1"> .... </div>
<div class="item" id="item-2"> .... </div>
<div class="item" id="item-3"> .... </div>
```

And by the way, I don't have access to the php server returning the data.

I want to get the id name in order to remove the div element with the same id first 
and append the response from the server.

last code I tried is

```
var targetDiv = $(response).find('.item');
alert(targetDiv);
```

thanks

Comment: `$(response).find('.item').attr('id')`

Comment: With the code you have provided, the alert should not be alerting undefined.

Comment: Please put the whole ajax code here

Comment: `$(response).filter('.item')`

Comment: `$(".item[id*='item']")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your element from `response` is the top level element so `find` will look in its descendants *only*.

You can wrap the returned element first (e.g. in a dummy div) to create a valid ancestor element to search from:

```
// Wrap the incoming HTML in a dummy element
var $div = $('<div>').html(response);

// Find the .item and alert its id
alert($div.find('.item').attr('id'));
```

Or (as suggested by others) you can filter the single item returned, but that may fail if there are multiple items returned. Stick with the wrapping trick.

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter()` and `map()`:

```
var idsToRemove = $(response).filter('.item').map(function () {
    return '#' + this.id;
}).get().join(',');

$(idsToRemove).remove(); // then remove old duplicates from DOM
```

### -DEMO-